# Objective C: warning on overriding init

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, instantiation

I have a class 'DOInstance' which I inherit later on. Here's its declaration:

```
@interface DOInstance : NSObject {

}

- (DOInstance *) initWithSynckey:(NSString *)_synckey;
@end
```

Then I have a subclass of DOInstance:

```
@interface Workflow_Workitem_Header_1px: DOInstance {

}
//- (Workflow_Workitem_Header_1px *) initWithSynckey:(NSString *)_synckey;
@end
```

I go ahead and implement it in the implementation file:

```
- (Workflow_Workitem_Header_1px *) initWithSynckey:(NSString *)_synckey {

    [super initWithSynckey:_synckey];
    //..
    //..
    return self;
}
```

Now, If I do not declare initWithSynckey: (the commented declaration above) in my subclass declaration, I get a warning at the implementation: "warning: initialization from distinct Objective-C type". If I declare it, this warning goes away. Okay.

Moving on:

I later do an instantiation of my subclass:

```
Workflow_Workitem_Header_1px *instance;
instance = [[Workflow_Workitem_Header_1px alloc] initWithSynckey:@"xxxx"];
```

Now, this gives me the same warning (irrespective of whether or not I declare the corresponding initWithSynckey: selector in my subclass. Namely, "warning: initialization from distinct Objective-C type".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I know the subclass has a weird name. Although it is handwritten currently, I later expect the subclass to be 'generated' based on some metadata.

Comment: So when you instantiate Workflow_Workitem_Header_1px I think it is returning the pointer already, so you can take out the star:
Workflow_Workitem_Header_1px instance = [[Workflow_Workitem_Header_1px alloc] initWithSynckey:@"xxxx"];

Does that work? 

You could also try replacing the return value of the constructor (Workflow_Workitem_Header_1px *) with id.

Comment: You must _always_ use pointers with Objective-C classes. In fact, you can't _not_ use them, because the compiler will tell you "error: statically allocated instance of Objective-C class 'NSString'" or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods named init... should have return type (id), not the type of the class.  Check out NSString.h and NSArray.h (among other classes) for examples.  That may be what is causing your problem.

Comment: Yes, that was in fact the problem. I did not know this until now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the overriding method must return the same type as the superclass' declaration.

DOInstance defines this:

```
- (DOInstance *) initWithSynckey:(NSString *)_synckey;
```

so Workflow_Workitem_Header_1px must look like this:

```
@interface Workflow_Workitem_Header_1px: DOInstance {
}
- (DOInstance *) initWithSynckey:(NSString *)_synckey;
@end
```

Any time you get the warning "warning: initialization from distinct Objective-C type" you're doing something in contravention of your typing: changing a method signature, and the like.

Comment: I was under the impression that it will not be a problem because the overridden method returns a subclass of type used by the original definition. I corrected it by having every level return (id) just like most of the NS* classes.

Comment: You're still returning an Objective-C instance and, because Objective-C is late-bound, as long as you're sending messages that the receiver understands, everything will still work.

The warning's there to tell you that you're monkeying with how you declared types, and the compiler's not prepared to _guarantee_ that things will work. Objective-C has _optional_ manifest typing.

You don't, in fact, need any type info at all: -foo { return [[NSString alloc] init] } is a perfectly acceptable method. (Well, "no type information" means "everything's an id".)